# compare total of each row with the rest of rows

Tags: python, list

what is the best way to compare the value of each row below to the rest. suppose i want to find that 2 or more rows have the same total (other than if statements).

each index below is originated from a random function.

import random
main_list = [random.randint(1,9) for iter in range(25)]

```
row_1_total = main_list[0] + main_list[1] + main_list[2] + main_list[3] + main_list[4]
row_2_total = main_list[5] + main_list[6] + main_list[7] + main_list[8] + main_list[9]
row_3_total = main_list[10] + main_list[11] + main_list[12] + main_list[13] + main_list[14]
row_4_total = main_list[15] + main_list[16] + main_list[17] + main_list[18] + main_list[19]
row_5_total = main_list[20] + main_list[21] + main_list[22] + main_list[23] + main_list[24]

print("Total of row 1 >>>", row_1_total)
print("Total of row 2 >>>", row_2_total)
print("Total of row 3 >>>", row_3_total)
print("Total of row 4 >>>", row_4_total)
print("Total of row 5 >>>", row_5_total)
```

Comment: Is your actual question: "how can I tell if two values in a collection of values are the same"? Your code seems very rudimentary and it's unclear what is in `main_list` or what its purpose is, but I'm assuming some type of number?

Comment: there you go >>> import random
main_list = [random.randint(1,9) for iter in range(25)]

Comment: If this is supposed to be a two-dimensional grid, why use a one-dimensional list? Do you just want a true/false answer to whether there are two rows with the same total, or do you want to find which rows they are? What if three rows are the same, or two pairs of rows are the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add the rows to data frame and use `df.diff().eq(0)` or any comparison

```
import pandas as pd
row_1_total=3
row_2_total=6
row_3_total=7
row_4_total=5
row_5_total=5
df= pd.DataFrame([row_1_total,row_2_total,row_3_total ,row_4_total ,row_5_total  ])
df.diff().eq(0)
print(df.diff().eq(0))
duplicat = df[df.duplicated()]
print(duplicat)
```

Comment: these are (25) random integers presented in 5 rows. all i want is to compare and find if 2 or more are equal to each other. There is no fixed value for the rows to be compared against/with.

Comment: I just give you an example. Try it.

Comment: it returns false for all rows even if 2 or more of them are equal.

Comment: Make sure about your data and print it and to see the code result run my example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 5 variables keep the sums in a list. If you loos loop you can take slice of the list in each iteration and reduce your code to

```
main_list = [random.randint(1, 9) for _ in range(25)]
sums = [sum(main_list[i:i+4]) for i in range(0, len(main_list), 5)]
for i in range(len(sums)):
    print(f"Total of row {i + 1} >>>", sums[i])
```

Now you can put `sums` in `set()` and compare the size

```
sums_set = set(sums)
print(len(sums_set) == len(sums))
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest collecting the totals in a slightly less unwieldy data structure, like a list:

```py
row_total = []
row_total.append(main_list[0] + main_list[1] + main_list[2] + main_list[3] + main_list[4])
row_total.append(main_list[5] + main_list[6] + main_list[7] + main_list[8] + main_list[9])
row_total.append(main_list[10] + main_list[11] + main_list[12] + main_list[13] + main_list[14])
row_total.append(main_list[15] + main_list[16] + main_list[17] + main_list[18] + main_list[19])
row_total.append(main_list[20] + main_list[21] + main_list[22] + main_list[23] + main_list[24])
print(row_total[3])
```

Secondly, you could avoid a lot of repetition by computing the totals in one line like this (assuming the `main_list` stops at 24):

```py
row_total = [sum(x[0+n:3+n]) for n in range(0, len(x), 3)]]
```

The answer to your question would then be something like:

```py
from collections import Counter
from random import randint

main_list = [randint(0, 10) for _ in range(25)]

row_total = [sum(main_list[0+n:3+n]) for n in range(0, len(main_list), 3)]

duplicate_totals = {t: c for t, c in Counter(row_total).items() if c > 1}

print(main_list)
# a dictionary of totals that show up twice or more often
print(duplicate_totals)
```

The result would look something like:

```
[4, 9, 1, 2, 0, 6, 8, 6, 4, 3, 0, 10, 0, 9, 1, 0, 10, 7, 10, 7, 0, 6, 2, 1, 7]
{17: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
main_list = [[5,4,6], [1, 2, 3, 4], [4,5,6]]
total = []
for row in main_list:
    total.append(sum(row))


for t in total:
    print("value : ",t, " is at indices : ", total.indices(t))
```

Comment: this is the main list >>> main_list = [random.randint(1,9) for iter in range(25)]

Comment: can you please include `main_list = [random.randint(1,9)` in original question. So that everyone get it.